# CardLayout - replace panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout

Is there an elegant way to replace a reference of an object which was added into a CardLayout with a new reference pointing to another object. I don't know if now I'm thinking well but I just want a feedback.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of bankAccPanel direct adding add it to a container (bankAccPanel  + anotherPanelNow). Then just swap cards in the subcontainer rather than main container.

Comment: The thing is that after LogInPanel I construct dynamically bankAccPanel (which is just a general framework at the begining) using the information from the database. Why I was asking for this "replace panel" is because of the Log Out feature which sends me back in this queue and I want to discard the old bankAccPanel which was modified according to the last user information to a new bankAccPanel().

Comment: So I cant add (bankAccPanel + anotherPanelNow) as u said, because maybe I will log in than log out as many times as I want.

Comment: I can remove all the content I've added for the current user logged in from the bankAccPanel() when he will log out. But I was just curious if this idea I asked can be easily done or not.

Comment: What if you just change model of the bankAccPanel (e.g. swap user DTO) and just reflect the changes in the same panel just by updating textfields, labels etc. ? Why do you need the panel recreation?

Comment: Ye ... this is what I've done ... everything works fine/perfect now :). It's just that I was curious if I can do what I've asked (It seemed easier at that moment and anyway I think my answer was in cardLayout API - because of bad habit I don't read carefully the API's - ). Anyway thx StanislavL